Can Tesla Wall Connector be mounted directly to stucco wall?
Can the Tesla Wall Connector be mounted directly on an exterior stucco wall without taking care of studs and such? Just want to make sure this would be strong enough.
The Wall Connector includes two fasteners, 5/32. Can I just use a 5/32 Masonry bit for the holes and mount with the included fasteners directly?
Or do I need a wall plug and/or special screws for stucco?

you need special stucco fasteners

@Traveler thank you , special stucco fasteners but wall plugs not required? And directly on stucco provides sufficient strength for an EVSE?

a wall plug will not hold in stucco, better solution is to take 3-4 inch  long wood screws to reach the plywood behind the stucco

@Traveler i do not have plywood though, it's a 1920 house. I think just lath behind. I have gotten these stucco screws: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Buildex-1-4-in-x-2-1-2-in-Steel-Hex-Washer-Head-Stucco-Anchors-with-Drill-Bit-25-Pack-31830/202067091  They are so long, I am sure they will hit wood behind as well. Does this look good or shall I return them?

If you have access to the inside of the wall you could add some blocking.  What's on the opposite side of the stucco wall?

Don't use  stucco screws. Use a Multi-Material screw.
Choose a length that is long enough to reach the wood behind the stucco.
Predrill an appropriate sized hole for the screw. Drilling through the stucco until you hit wood. This will tell you what length screw you need. Aim to get at least 3/4" into wood.
Before attaching anything, fill the holes with caulk. Even latex painters caulk will work to help prevent water from getting in the holes.
Install the device.  If it is in an area that gets heavy rain, address that issue. (caulk around the box, build a small roof over it, etc.)

Just do double check, just before screwing in the screw I fill the drilled hole with caulk? Acrylic one (BEHR Multipurpose Siliconized Acrylic Caulk) is fine?

Yep that will work if you are covering the screws. If it is in a place where you will be painting, just be sure the caulk is paintable.
